# How to chain like element with PHP DOMDocument?

Tags: php, html, dom, domdocument

I am seeking to construct a HTML table using DOMDocument. For example the first row (header row) of the table would look like this:

```
<tr><th>text</th><th>text</th><th>text</th><th>text</th><th>text</th><th>text</th></tr>
```

The table row (<tr>) followed by several table header tags (<th>, also the <td> tag) chained together.

I have tried the following which seemed logical:

```
$dom_obj = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');

// First the initial table tag.
$table = $dom_obj->createElement('table');
$dom_obj->appendChild($table);

// Table row
$tr = $dom_obj->createElement('tr');
$table->appendChild($tr);

// For loop ??
$th = $dom_obj->createElement('th');
$tr->appendChild($th);

$th = $dom_obj->createElement('th');
$th->appendChild($th);

$html_out = $dom_obj->saveHTML();
```

I received the following error message:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught DOMException: Hierarchy Request Error . . . . . . .

By the best that I can tell this means DOMDocument doesn't like that I am trying to attach like elements together.

I also tried the following, uniquely naming the <th> as I went:

```
$dom_obj = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');

// First the initial table tag.
$table = $dom_obj->createElement('table');
$dom_obj->appendChild($table);

// Table row
$tr = $dom_obj->createElement('tr');
$table->appendChild($tr);

// For loop ??
$th1 = $dom_obj->createElement('th');
$tr->appendChild($th1);

$th2 = $dom_obj->createElement('th');
$th1->appendChild($th2);

$html_out = $dom_obj->saveHTML();
```

This gave the following results:

> <table><tr><th><th></th></th></tr></table>

Still not what is needed.

**How can I chain the <th> or <td> together using PHP DOMDocument?**

Comment: You got the 'Hierarchy Request Error'  because you tried to append `$th` to itself, with `$th->appendChild($th);`, which doesn't make sense. You probably made a typo and meant to write `$tr->appendChild($th);` just like a few lines before.

Answer (score 1):

After further experimentation I succeeded in getting what I was after. I tried the following:

```
$dom_obj = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');

// First the initial table tag.
$table = $dom_obj->createElement('table');
$dom_obj->appendChild($table);

// Table row
$tr = $dom_obj->createElement('tr');
$table->appendChild($tr);

// For loop here??
$th = $dom_obj->createElement('th');
$tr->appendChild($th);

$th = $dom_obj->createElement('th');
$tr->appendChild($th);

$html_out = $dom_obj->saveHTML();
```

I appended  more <th> tags directly to the <tr> tag which gives the effect of chained together <th> tags.

> <table><tr><th></th><th></th></tr></table>

Not exactly intuitive, but, what ever works. I am now presupposing that to add more rows to my table I need attach the <tr> tags directly to the <table> tag.

Now I can build a table in code adding database information as I go.